# Python why I can't add a list to a list?

Tags: python, list, variables, combinations

I have the following code, I'm supposed to find all the combinations available using 8 numbers (only 1,3,5,7,9), I have to sum them and have sum 20, example:

```
import random
import time
numbers = [1,3,5,7,9]
values = []
combinations = 0
combinations_found = []

while combinations != 11:
    n = random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
    n = numbers[n]    
            
    if len(values) >= 8:
        if sum(values) == 20:
            values.sort()
            combinations_found.sort()
            if [values] in combinations_found:
                values.clear()
                None
            else:
                combinations_found.append(values)
                combinations +=1

        values.clear()        
        
    else:
        values.append(n)
```

The problem is that when it finds a combination it doesn't add it to my variable combinations_found, any help?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `values.clear()`.  That re-uses the same list that gets appended to `combinations_found`, so you are always appending the **same** list reference.  When you clear it, you end up with a bunch of references to empty lists.

Instead, use `values = []` to start a new list.

Comment: Why do methods like `.clear()` even exist?  Python seems to greatly favour "redefining" a variable than "reusing" it pretty much everywhere.  Do you have any examples where reuse would be preferred?